# return $add ref of Firebase item AngularFire

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Let's say I have a collection of items:

```
var itemsRef = new Firebase("https://example.firebaseio.com/items");  
$scope.items = $firebase(itemsRef);
```

And we `$add` an item:

```
$scope.items.$add($scope.item);
```

I understand the ref gets generated client side before making it to the Firebase collection.

**How do I get that ref after adding the item?** *For example* `-Jx8363hdu12`

*AngularFire 0.6.0*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of *AngularFire 0.6.0* `$add`, `$save`, `$set` and `$remove` use promises:

https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/issues/183

```
$scope.items.$add($scope.item).then(function(p){
  console.log(p.name());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For others coming by here if you had code that previously worked using

```
 var bleh = $scope.items.$add($scope.item);
```

Previously $add would return the actual value, but as Dan mentioned above it was changed to return a promise.

You have two options (the later being the better).

1. Move back to an older version of angularfire.
2. You will HAVE to use the .then operation.

I have had this problem a few times and keep running into it (i'm hoping the more variations on the term can be found the more likely if it happens again to me or others it'll be easier to find).

I had it in my head that a promise meant that you could still use the variable and at some point in the future it would fill it in (so I kept thinking that it would fill it in eventually and was getting annoyed that it never seemed to).

From here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

```
Here's how you use that promise:

promise.then(function(result) {
  console.log(result); // "Stuff worked!"
}, function(err) {
  console.log(err); // Error: "It broke"
});
"then" takes two arguments, a callback for a success case, and another for the failure case. Both are optional, so you can add a callback for the success or failure case only.
```

So in theory if firebase errors out saving the data (adding/removing/etc) you should at least have the error function so you can trap that something wrong has happened.

For Dan's example:

```
$scope.items.$add($scope.item).then(
function(p){
  console.log(p.name());
}, 
function(err){
  console.log("The expected Firebase action failed to occur this was your error: " + err);
});
```